# Size medium or large

Tags: frames

I am buying a cube hanzz pro freeride but I cant decide on the size. The dealer has only Medium size so I cant ride the large one. I am 182 cm tall 76kg and have step length of 89cm. What shall I do?

Comment: Surely trying the medium size will tell you everything?  Also you're the same height as me, so I imagine a large frame will have too long a reach.

Comment: XC i ride a large which is perfect. for a freeride the dealer told me go with the medium will have better handling

Comment: There are better, more general questions about sizing frames - e.g. http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/explaining-the-effects-of-frame-geometries?rq=1, http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4030/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-riding-a-smaller-mountain-bike-fram?rq=1 - this question will be of little use to anyone else even if someone can productively answer the original.

Comment: I'd be suspicious of any dealer advising me to buy what he has in stock, even if it's a bit too small. I can't find it, but didn't we have a question along the lines of "The bike I want is either too small or too large, which should I get?" If so, this is a duplicate of that, but IMO not of the others.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying another dealer and taking your potential next bike for a spin. They should allow at least ride in their parking lot.

Bike sizing is important, do not try to save a buck buying a bike which does not fit.